# Is this claim about limit of multivariable functions correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

let $ f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{m} $.

define a projection function $ \pi^{i}$ by:
$ \pi^{i}\left(x_{1},...,x_{n}\right)=x_{i} $.

Is it true that $ \underset{x\to x_{0}}{\lim}f\left(x\right)=\overline{l} $ if and only if for and $ 1\leq i\leq n $ it follows that $ \pi^{i}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\underset{\pi^{i}\left(x\right)\to\pi^{i}\left(x_{o}\right)}{\longrightarrow}\pi^{i}\left(\overline{l}\right) $

At first I thought I proved this theorem (because the equvivalent theorem holds for sequences), but I though that maybe iterated limits contradict this statement so Im not sure that my proof is correct (maybe I made some assumptions werent correct).

So I'll be glad if someone can tell if this statement is true or not. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is true. just observe that
$|\pi^j(f(x)) - \ell_j| \leq \|f(x) -\ell\| \leq \sqrt{m} \max\limits_{j=1\ldots m}\{|\pi^j(f(x)) - \ell_j|\}$